# Utilisation de pouvoir avec le subjonctif

Tags: verbes, subjonctif, auxiliaires

Pour traduire « I gave him some money so he could go see a movie », pourrais-je dire :

> Je lui ai donné de l'argent pour qu'il aille voir un film

au lieu de :

> Je lui ai donné de l'argent pour qu'il puisse aller voir un film

en omettant « pouvoir » ? On m'a dit que le premier est plus courant.

Comment: Les deux sont justes en ce qui concerne ma grammaire interne. J'imagine que si le premier est plus courant, c'est parce qu'un seul auxiliaire c'est moins fatiguant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont possibles. Le sens est similaire mais pas tout à fait identiques.

« Pour qu'il aille voir un film » implique que le locuteur s'attend à ce que l'argent soit utilisé pour voir un film. Si celui qui reçoit l'argent l'utilise finalement pour autre chose, je risque de ne pas être content.

« Pour qu'il puisse aller voir un film » est beaucoup moins fort de ce point de vue. Si l'argent est utilisé pour autre chose, ce n'est plus mon problème.

Cela dit, la différence n'est pas très marquée. Comme Evpok l'a remarqué, on a tendance à utiliser la première variante simplement parce que la deuxième est lourde.

Comment: Ne manque pas le premier un semi-auxillaire d'aspect:

Comment: @Micromégas Justement non, l'auxiliaire d'aspect n'est pas nécessaire.